# Run code on cells that don't end with "PDF"

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to do some renaming and I do not want the code to run if the last 3 characters = pdf. Should be simple, but when I run the macro the renaming works fine but it deletes every cell that ends with pdf.

```
SearchChar = "pdf"

For Each bCell In rng.Cells
Select Case Len(bCell)
Case 2
    If Right(bCell, 3) <> SearchChar Then 'This must be wrong
        val = SearchSite & Left(bCell, 1) & "00" & Mid(bCell, 2, 1) & "1.pdf"
    End If
End Select
bCell.Value = val
Next
```

Comment: `Case 2` looks suspect, because for a cell to contain `"pdf"` it's len must be greater than or equal to 3.

Comment: So im asking excel to determine the LEN so it can run the formula to change it from a simple name to the actual filename. Example `A1 should turn into 173A0011.pdf`

Comment: The body of your `Case 2` block will *never* execute if the length of the cell <> 2. So, you need to determine under what conditions that block ought to execute, and either modify your `Case` or add a different `Case` statement to account for that condition(s).

Comment: What does your data look like? Examples would help. Also, remove/comment out your `Select Case` stuff. As mentioned, it's not going to run on *any* cell that's greater than length 2...which I assume is all cells, but especially cells with `pdf` in them anywhere.

Comment: I only showed `Case 2` to keep the code here small. I have a Case 2,3,4,8,9,10,11,12. When i run the code everything works fine. but if i run the code to convert simple naming to actual naming `ie., A1 = Simple, 173A0011.pdf = actual` with a cell that ends in "PDF" then it removes that cell for some reason. So i thought my problem was in my `If(Right...` line. I want to say If last 3 characters of cell in range = "PDF" then skip Else run formula.

Comment: Do you use `Option Compare Text`? If not, go for `lcase(Right(bCell, 3)) <> SearchChar`, since comparisons in VBA are case sensitive by default.

Comment: It seems to be an error with my  `Case Else
        If LCase(Right(bCell, 3)) <> SearchChar Then
            val = (bCell)
        End If`

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried changing your If statement to check if the right 3 characters are pdf, then "nothing" else your code?  Would be similar to:

```
If Right(bCell,3)=SearchChar Then
'Nothing
Else
val = SearchSite & Left(r, 1) & "00" & Mid(r, 2, 1) & "1.pdf"
bCell.Value=val
End If
```

My guess is that where the last 3 characters are pdf, val = nothing, so what is printed out is bCell.Value= nothing, so it deletes it.  I moved that inside the else section.

Comment: This got me on the right track. 
       `If LCase(Right(bCell, 3)) = SearchChar Then
            val = bCell Else` Inserted this in below each case statement.

Answer (score 0):

You may try like this to rename selection items not ending with "pdf"

```
Set rng = Selection
SearchChar = "pdf"
Select Case n
    Case 2
        For Each r In rng
            If Right(r, 3) <> SearchChar Then 'This must be wrong
                r = SearchSite & Left(r, 1) & "00" & Mid(r, 2, 1) & "1.pdf"
            End If
        Next
End Select
```